# unable to access object property inside another property in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a object inside service in angularjs with some properties defined.

```
eReaderBook.service("eReaderService", ["$window", function ($window) {
'use strict';
this.options = {
    viewstate : "Single1",
    pageSrc : ""
};
this.loadXmlData = function () {
    this.options.viewstate = "Multi"        
};
}]);
```

i want to access the viewstate property of this.options inside this.loadXmlData function. while doing so it throws a error. how to access the property inside this.loadXmlData function.

Answer (score 0):

Error in your object.Remove the ,(comma) after pageSrc.

Comment: k changed can u help now

Answer (score 0):

your loadXmlData function is not valid JS code

```
function () {
  this.options.viewstate : "Multi"        
};
```

if you want write into `options.viewstate` property you must use =

```
function () {
  this.options.viewstate = "Multi";        
};
```

colon is used only in object literal definition (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)